# How can I enter multiple doubles into a textbox separated by commas and store in an Array which holds doubles?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am trying to enter multiple values into a textbox and when I press a button they will be stored in an array. Like this: 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5 Then press the button and they are stored in index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

I understand that the values are a string and need to be converted, I think I am close to the answer but I am not sure, here is what I have been trying:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //five values entered from textbox
        string values = textBox1.Text;
        string[] EmailArr = values.Split(',');
        double[] yArray = new double[5] = Array.ConvertAll(values.Split(','), Double.Parse);
    }
```

I know this is wrong, but is it along the right lines? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the linq way :

```
var yArray = textBox1.Text
                     .Split(',')
                     .Select(m => Double.Parse(m.Trim()))
                     .ToArray();
```

By the way, don't use that with a TextChanged event, rather with a Validated, or a Clicked on your button.

**Edit**

Follow this steps :

Double click on "YourForm".cs (to have the "design").

Select your TextBox.

Right click, choose "Properties".

See the "Event list".

Remove anything on line "TextChanged"

DoubleClick on line **Validated** (this will add text on this line)

This should open the "code" part.

Past my answer's code into the new method "private void textBox1_Validated(...)"

Remove all the code present in your question.

Comment: for the records, I find your solution better, but I wanted to give him another view, which is always good...

Comment: I will try this now, hopefully I can make it work. Thanks you!

Comment: I have been trying this, but as soon as I type a comma in the textbox I get an error saying "input string was not in a correct format" Any idea what is causing this? Thank you!

Comment: @deucalion0 oh, just change the event, remove the TextChanged event from your textbox, add an Click event on your button, or a Validated on your TextBox.

Comment: Thanks for that, I changed it to this but am still getting the same error textBox1_Validating, I am not sure if this is right? Thank you!

Comment: @deucalion0 Hope you didn't just change `textBox1_TextChanged`to `textBox1_Validating` did you ?

Comment: No sorry, I changed it to textBox1_Validated, I looked up MSDN, and I thought this was correct. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @deucalion0 see my Edit, maybe ;=)

Comment: Thank you, that worked I got rid of the error, but the values are not being added to my array, I will keep messing about with it, you have got me this far, I appreciate that!! Thank you!

Comment: @deucalion0 well I just tried it and it works, with you sample "textbox content" and  a Validated event... Try to debug step by step (put a break point in the event) and see what's happening, maybe...

Comment: Can you please give me the code you used to test, I think it may be how I have the button even set up, I will keep trying until I get it to work, many thanks Raphael.

Comment: You are a genius, I see how you done it and I copied it, my code works perfectly now, thank you very much for your time!!!

Answer (score 2):

or the older fashion way:

```
    string values = textBox1.Text;
    string[] EmailArr = values.Split(',');
    double[] dlbArr = new double[EmailArr.Length];
    int index = 0;
    foreach (string item in EmailArr)
    {
        dlbArr[index] = Convert.ToDouble(item[index]);
        index++;
    }
```